# How do I make my horse stop following me?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I summoned an assassin horse, and now I can't get it to stop following me. It's making it very difficult to do anything. How can I make it leave me alone, or at least just stand and wait for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just go somewhere he can't. Like up a cliff or over some water or fast travel. The horse despawns when you get somewhere between 50 and 100m away from it.

Comment: My favorite was getting it stuck on a rock. For some reason it'd let me hop up onto rocks but not hop down from them. It's just stand there.

Comment: @animuson: Somehow I managed to get my horse to follow me onto a fallen tree.  Then it was stuck standing upright in a weird angle (rotated on the tree).

Comment: This would never work on Skyrim horses.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your position and how hard it is to get back there i would advise to just teleport away using your map to a location mark and then get back where you were. This will take care of the horse.

Answer (score -4):

If you just shoot it, you'll get a small warning about killing animals, but it does the trick.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty extreme solution, and you make it sound as if there are others.